# heroku Unexpected error while processing request: no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jruby

Running Windows, ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32], rails 3.2.11, runs OK locally but on Heroku get

> Unexpected error while processing request: no such file to load

files in question were "Time" and "Date" and "Yaml"

changed app code from

```
require 'Time'
```

to

```
require 'time'
```

which fixed problem.

Suspect due to Heroku running JRuby which is case-sensitive for "require"
Maybe related to 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JIRA ticket in question is for resolving Java package names, not Ruby library names.

MRI behaves this way, too, if it's on a case-sensitive file system:

```
$ cat Hello.rb 
def foo
  "UPPER"
end
$ cat hello.rb 
def foo
  "lower"
end
$ ruby2.0 -v -I . -r hello -e 'p foo'
ruby 2.1.0dev (2013-04-01 trunk 40028) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
"lower"
$ ruby2.0 -v -I . -r Hello -e 'p foo'
ruby 2.1.0dev (2013-04-01 trunk 40028) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
"UPPER"
```

My advice is not to assume that the underlying filesystem is case-insensitive.

Comment: quite right ... not a Jruby thing at all but file-system case sensitivty